# R analyse string in column of a big data frame and give value in a separate column

Tags: r, string

I have a data frame with 20 columns. One of the columns is made up of strings. I would like to analyse the strings for positions of specific alphabets in R and then assign a value based on this in a different column. For example, if the strings are ABCDEF, AADFEG, I would like to create a new column with values, with 1 if A is in position 1. 1,2 if A is in position 1,2. 7 if G is in position 6. I have been trying to use str_locate and also if_else and then mutate using dplyr package but not sure if there is an easier way to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: so shouldn't you have 26+1=27 columns, 1 for string and other 26 for 26 alphabets?

Comment: What is the output for the string "AACCCG" - A is in position 1 and 2, and G is in position 6. Should the result be `1`, `2`, `7`, `127` or something else?

Comment: A small reproducible example with sample input and desired output would help clear the intent.

Comment: Apologies for not making it clearer. But I wanted the output to be 1,2. The code below from mat.tho works. I can use it to add the other letters as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've created a small code snippet:

```
df<-data.frame(a=c("ABCDEF","AADFEG","TRETGTGA"))
df$b<-lapply(gregexpr(pattern = 'A', df$a), function(x) c(unlist(x)) )
```

Here, you apply a regex at each entry of the vector **df$a** and find the pattern **A**, resulting for the indices of all **A**s. With **lapply** the results (=indices) are extracted. At the end you assign the result to a new column in the dataframe.

#### note

If the pattern can't be found, -1 is shown.